# toString(16) with a decimal point

Tags: javascript, tostring

I understand it for binary, but I'm not comprehending it for hex.

Here's some examples:

```
Number(0.15).toString(16) // 0.26666666666666
Number(1.5).toString(16) // 1.8
Number(.18).toString(16) // 0.2e147ae147ae14
```

It looks like the decimal is increased by about 40% when converted to hex, which doesn't really make sense when you're going from base 10 to base 16. It should go down as it would with whole numbers, right?

If it is/isn't correct: how do you do this by hand? I fully understand converting integers but I haven't found a source on converting dec to hex when the dec value has a decimal.

Comment: What you are seeing is the hex representation of the binary number - which in turn is typically "as many bits as there are in the number". Most decimals cannot be expressed exactly as a binary number. So you see "as many as can be shown". If you print the number `0.18` in decimal you will see it goes on and on.

Comment: @Floris I'm not sure if that is a complete explanation here. It's not like the values are a "small bit" off. Rather, "it looks like the decimal is increased by about 40% when converted to hex" .. So what *are* the rules for conversion of a non-whole number?

Comment: @Floris So it's essentially converting to binary and then taking groups of 4 and directly converting to hex, right? 3.625 = 11.101 in binary, but since that is only a group of 3 after the decimal, it changes it to 11.1010, which in turn becomes 3.A in Hex. So that's how it does it, but is that actually mathematically correct? I don't think the hex should ever be higher than the decimal.

Comment: Yes that is correct. DesertIvy's answer explains it very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't think of the decimal as "increasing by about 40%." The numbers are equal - they're just represented using different number systems.

Let's take a look at what's going on when you convert a decimal number to binary, then to hex. For me, at least, this makes it a little easier to understand:

Take the decimal number `0.15`: In binary, it's `0.0010 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110...`. (Spaces added for clarity.) Notice anything interesting? If you convert each of these chunks of four bits to the hex equivalents, you get exactly what your `toString(16)` evocation gave you: `0.2666666...` (`0010` in binary = `2` in hex).

Why is it this way? Because after the decimal point, you can think of each entry as an **inverse power of 2**. Meaning each bit after the decimal point represents:

```
 .1 |  .01 |  .001 |  .0001 |  .00001... (BIN)
0.5 | 0.25 | 0.125 | 0.0625 | 0.03125... (DEC)
```

So how would we represent `1.5` in *binary*? Well, everything before the decimal should be easy (it's just `1`), but after that, we simply stop at `1.1` (binary), since `1 + 0.5` (decimal) = `1.5` (decimal)  = `1.1000` (binary).

I threw some extra zeros in there to make this next conversion easier, because next we take that chunk of four bits and convert it to hex, which is simply `1.8`.

Comment: What I don't get is why is the zero put on the right instead of the left? E.g. 3.625 = 11.101, a zero is added to the right since there aren't 4 digits after the decimal, which makes 11.1010. This converts to 3.A. A is higher than 6, which would make it seem as though 3.625 decimal is a smaller number than 3.A hex. It would make more sense if the zero was added to the left, creating 11.0101 or 3.5. 3.5 is lower than 3.625 and befitting of a higher base. I know you're not wrong, but it seems backwards.

Comment: Well, `11.0101` in binary is not `3.5` in decimal. It's actually `2 + 1 + .25 + .0625 = 3.3125`. The zero is put on the left because that's simply how numbers are written, regardless of their base. Think of it this way: I could add any number of `0`s to the right of any number because it won't change the value: `3.14 = 3.140000...` But if I start adding zeros to the *right* of my numbers, bad things happen: `3.14 != 3.014`. Number systems of different bases work exactly the same, but we simply change when we "carry."

Comment: After the decimal is handled separately from the number on the left. E.g. it seems equivalent to 14 being compared to 014, rather than .14 being compared to .014. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I guess the best way of looking at it is that the 0-9 of the decimal number is being stretched across the spectrum of 0-F of the hex number. This causes hex decimals to be greater than dec decimals due to the inverse nature of decimals.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it figured out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question that I have never thought about before, but after a little research, makes complete sense.

If you wanted to represent the decimal value `24` in hex, you would divide the value by 16 like this: 24/16 = 1, remainder 8 ---> so the "16's" digit in hex is 1 and the "1's" digit is 8, giving you the final hex value of `18`.

The "fractional" part of a decimal number goes through a sort of similar process, but, instead of dividing by 16, you multiply by 16.  So, using your examples, you can step through the process:

Decimal number `0.15` = Hexidecimal number `0.26666666666666`

- .15 * 16 = 2.4 ---> hex value `0.2` (keep the 2, carry over .4)
- .4 * 16 = 6.4 ---> hex value `0.26` (keep the 6, carry over .4)
- .4 * 16 = 6.4 ---> hex value `0.266` (keep the 6, carry over .4)
- .4 * 16 = 6.4 ---> hex value `0.2666` (keep the 6, carry over .4)
- . . . .

Decimal number `1.5` = Hexidecimal number `1.8`

- 1.5 ---> hex value `1` (keep the 1, carry over .5)
- .5 * 16 = 8 ---> hex value `1.8`

Decimal number `.18` = Hexidecimal number `0.2e147ae147ae14`

- .18 * 16 = 2.88 ---> hex value `0.2` (keep the 2, carry over .88)
- .88 * 16 = 14.08 ---> hex value `0.2e` (keep the 14 [or "e"], carry over .8)
- .08 * 16 = 1.28 ---> hex value `0.2e1` (keep the 1, carry over .28)
- .28 * 16 = 4.48 ---> hex value `0.2e14` (keep the 4, carry over .48)
- . . . .

It actually makes a lot of sense once you step through it a bit, but it's certainly not something that presents itself clearly at first glance.   :)